# changing view background according to value

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I want to have a textview which represents a rating, and I wanted the background to go from light to dark according to the value. meaning 1=white background and 5=red background. What do you think the best way of doing this would be?

Thanks

Amit

Comment: when would the color change?  as soon as the user types in the value or once they leave the `textview` completely?

Answer (score 0):

For binding `BackgroundColor`:

- MvvmCross includes a `BackgroundColor` binding and there is an example of it being used with a `TextView` in [ValueConversion sample in View_Colors.axml](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/ValueConversion/ValueConversion.UI.Droid/Resources/Layout/View_Colors.axml)

  ```
  <TextView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="100dp"
      local:MvxBind="BackgroundColor Color, Converter=NativeColor; Text Color; TextColor Color, Converter=ContrastColor" 
  />
  ```

For converting from an int to an colo(u)r:

- I'd recommend you use a ValueConverter which inherits from [MvxColorConverter.vs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Plugins/Cirrious/Color/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Color/MvxColorValueConverter.cs) - e.g. something like:

  ```
       public void RatingColorConverter : MvxColorConverter
       {
           protected override MvxColor Convert(object value, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
           {
               switch ((int)value)
               {
                   case 1:
                      return new MvxColor(255,255,255);
                   case 2:
                      return new MvxColor(255,200,200);
                   // etc
               }
           }
       }
  ```